# hashmap in persistence manager

Tags: java, google-app-engine, persistence

so I am trying to build a google app engine using servlets, filters etc. I have a java file that looks something like:

```
public class Idea implements Comparator<Idea> {
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key key;

@Persistent
private User author;

@Persistent
private String content;

@Persistent
private Date date;

@Persistent
private Map<User, Boolean> positiveVotes ;

@Persistent
private Map<User, Boolean> negativeVotes;

public Idea(User author, String content, Date date) {
    this.author = author;
    this.content = content;
    this.date = date;
    this.positiveVotes = new HashMap<User, Boolean>();
    this.negativeVotes = new HashMap<User, Boolean>();
}
```

but when I try to run my program, I get an exception stack beginning with:

```
Feb 13, 2010 5:01:23 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /sign
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: positiveVotes: java.util.HashMap is not a supported property type.
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedSingleValue(DataTypeUtils.java:145)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:127)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity.setProperty(Entity.java:280)
```

So, my question is why does it complain that java.util.HashMap is not a supported property type, and also what could I do to work around it. Thanks! hope someone replies soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a supported type for serialization.  You can review [the list](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/docs/java/datastore/dataclasses.html#Collections) of supported types, and consider alternative designs.  I could be missing something, but can you just keep sets of the users who support or oppose the idea?  What is the purpose of the boolean?  Note that HashSet is a supported type.

Comment: so what can i do if i want to have a map field in my class?

Comment: Can you show more code, or explain the purpose of the boolean value?

Comment: actually i noticed hashmap is actually serializable http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html.

Comment: Yes, it implements Serializable, but App Engine does not support persisting it.

Comment: the purpose of boolean is in my jstl code in my jsp file. i m using scriptless jsp and i need boolean to see if a user voted for a particular idea.

Comment: so u just can't persist a map of any kind in app engine?

Comment: No, maps can't be persisted.  Can you keep sets or lists of the users who voted up and down?  That is supported.

Comment: i tried working with lists but i really map apparently. the thing is from jstl, i can't call a method on my idea object by passing in parameter. so the only alternative is to use a map and see if a user has a mapping.

Answer (score 5):

You can ask GAE to store the HashMap as a Blob value by adding the JDO annotation to flag this field as being stored serialised:

@Persistent(serialized="true")

https://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/docs/java/datastore/dataclasses.html#Serializable_Objects

Comment: Very helpful! The same code also makes a custom Serializable class persistable.

Answer (score 0):

private Map positiveVotes;

Keeping a hashmap to see if the user has voted or not might become extremely inefficient if the number of users becomes large.

why dont you keep a class like this:

```
class Votes {
private Key key;
private Key ideaId;
private User voter;
private Boolean positive; // true is positive, false is negative
}
```

and for every idea just query the Votes table to see if the user has voted for the idea. if he has was it positive or negative.

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Votes.class);
query.setFilter("ideaId == :ideaIdParam && user == :userParam");
List<Votes> userVotes = query.execute(ideaId, user);
if(userVotes != null && !userVotes.isEmpty()){
return userVotes.get(0).getPositive(); // this gives the users reaction
}
else {
return null; // this means no reaction
}
```

you can now use this to get a particular users reaction or loop over the list and get all users reactions by removing the userParam from query.